# Effeciency of route class handling HTTP requests in php

Tags: php, routes

On my php project, i use the .htaccess file to handle request with a cleaner url and route it to the appropriate file. However i am making plans to use a route class which would resolve the url just like how laravel's Route:: works.
My question is which is more effective, which takes less time and which should i rather use?

Comment: its unlikely that in the real world the speed would make any difference. But if you really want to know. the only way is to benchmark it your self.

Comment: The one you chose to go with wouldn't be easily maintainable on large set of URLs along with time to time manual modifications  on introducing new routes. So stick with defining a a router class inside your application.